# Checking the Winner on Tic Tac Toe game on Windows Form Application - C++

Tags: c++, windows, forms

I'm making a Tic-Tac-Toe game as a Windows Form Application for my C++ class and I need help on making a function to find a winner. In the void winner function, I'm checking to see if three squares match but I'm not sure if the condition in the if statement is right. The program worked well but when I added the void winner function, it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

```
private: System::Void A1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

   bool turn = true;

   if (turn)
      A1->Text = "X";

   else
      A1->Text = "O";

   turn = !turn;
   winner();
}

 void winner()
{
   if (A1 = A2 && A2 == A3)
      label1-> Text= "Winner";           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement inside if(), you have missed an equal sign, which might be causing all the problem. You are actually assigning `A1` to `A2`. Try this,

```
if (A1==A2 && A2==A3)
```

Also, what I think you must be trying to do is compare the `Text` attribute of A1, A2 and A3. For that purpose use,

```
if(A1->Text==A2->Text && A2->Text==A3->Text)
```